# React sinon/enzyme simulate click on es6 class function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, sinon, enzyme

i want to test button click on react component that is typescript class.
This is component code:

```
export default class Send extends Component ... {

 constructor(super) {...}

 selectAll() {...}

 render() {
  <button id="selectAll" onClick={this.selectAll.bind(this)}>Add<button/>
 }
}
```

My test is:

```
it('should select all if selectAll button is clicked', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Send {...props} />);
    const selectAll = sinon.spy(wrapper.instance(), 'selectAll');

    const selectAllButton = wrapper.find('#selectAll');

    selectAllButton.simulate('click');

    expect(selectAll.calledOnce).to.equal(true);

  });
```

And this is what i get:

```
      AssertionError: expected false to equal true
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you add the code for selectAll?

Comment: @Ori selectAll just sets the state with setState(), no return value.

Comment: Move `this.selectAll.bind(this)` to the constructor -> `this.selectAll = this.selectAll.bind(this)`, change onclick to `onClick={this.selectAll}`, and use` sinon.spy(Send.prototype, 'selectAll');`.

Comment: @OriDrori Edit: i've changed it and still the same error

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i've found what was the problem. I had to add

```
wrapper.instance().forceUpdate();
```

right after declaring sinon.spy(...), and now it works fine.